# Running native mongodb commands in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using Mongoid, but all I need to do is increment a field which is an integer. Would it be worth it for me to skip using Mongoid's methods, and just run the mongodb ruby drivers method to increment a value?

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mu is too short is correct, you could either use the built in mongoid #inc method:

```
Model.inc(:field, integer)
```

Or you could access the collection directly via the collection attribute:

```
Model.collection.update(
  { query document },
  { "$inc" => { :field => value } }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use Mongoid's [`inc`](http://mongoid.org/docs/persistence/atomic.html#inc) method?

> **Model#inc**
>
> Performs MongoDB's [`$inc`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24inc) modifier which increments it's value by the supplied amount or initializes it to that value. If the field is not numeric an error will be raised.

So doing `model.inc(:a, 11)` should send an `{ $inc: { a: 11 } }` update straight into MongoDB.